# AngularJS + update graph in amCharts

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dom-events

I'm having difficulty with angularJS to update the graph correctly after a query returns on a service.

Basically after the query return, I need to display the chart according to the return, but the chart does not seem to load anymore, how can I do a reload in the amcharts chart?

Here's an example.

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', ['amChartsDirective']);
  app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http) {

    function getDataJSON(){
      return {
        data: [{ year: 2007, income: 30.1, expenses: 23.9 }, { year: 2008, income: 29.5, expenses: 25.1 }],
        type: "serial", categoryField: "year", categoryAxis: { gridPosition: "start",parseDates: false },
        valueAxes: [{ position: "top", title: "Million USD" }], graphs: [{ type: "column", fillAlphas: 1 }] };
    };

    $scope.amChartOffLine = getDataJSON();
    $scope.amChartOnLine = '';

    $http({ url: 'https://apps.widenet.com.br/busca-cep/api/cep/06233-030.json', method: 'GET' })
      .then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log('return: '+response.data.city);
        $scope.amChartOnLine = getDataJSON();
        console.log('Display graph ?');
      });
    });

    console.log('finish.');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xpgydef3/6/

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div style="height: 300px; width: 400px;">
   <am-chart id="OffLine" options="amChartOffLine"></am-chart>
  </div>
  <div style="height: 300px; width: 400px;">
   <am-chart id="OnLine" options="amChartOnLine"></am-chart>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is your expected return that your missing? 'osasco'?

Comment: @alphapilgrim Forget Osasco, I used it just to exemplify it. I would just like to display the graph after the http.get return.
Note that the chart is not created after the http.get return.

Comment: https://github.com/GrantMStevens/amCharts-Angular